# How would I make this create a new TextView everytime I message is received

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Basically the code I have can tell if it's the user sending the message or the other party.  What I want to do is create a new clientVIEW which is a TextView and place it below the on that is currently there everytime a message is received.  How would I create a new TextView everytime?   Would it be

```
ClientView = new ClientView(this)
```

then

```
ClientView.append(event.getSender(): event.getMessage());
```

Current code

```
if (!event.getSender().equals(Utils.USER_NAME)){
            clientView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            clientView.append("\n"+event.getSender() +" : "+event.getMessage());
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

to create new `textview` all you have to do is

```
TextView text = new TextView(context);
```

every time you receive a message, you'll have to append that text to your layout tho, so pass a reference to your layout and use `layout.addView()`